# datatable, pasar datos a modal mediante boton

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, datatables

Tengo una datatable CRUD con botones y quiero hacerla responsive con la libreria de datatables pero al hacer responsive no pasan los datos a el modal.

al dar click en el boton deben pasar los datos al modal para editarlos, pero en el movil siendo responsive la datatable abre el modal en blanco.

Es una datatable CRUD para agregar, editar y eliminar datos de la table, en la version normal de escritorio funciona, pero en el movil se hace responsive con row child details y al dar al boton de editar muestra el modal pero vacios los campos input.

[image: bn]

[image: mal]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var id, opcion;

tablaUsuarios = $('#tablaUsuarios').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "serverside/serversideUsuarios.php",
        responsive: {
           details: {
               display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal( {
                   header: function ( row ) {
                       var data = row.data();
                       return 'Details for '+data[0]+' '+data[1];
                   }
               } ),
              renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll( {
                   tableClass: 'table'
               } )
           }
       }
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "defaultContent": "<div class='wrapper text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-info btn-sm btnEditar' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Editar' style='margin-right: 15px'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Eliminar'><span class='material-icons'>delete</span></button></div></div>"
        } ],
});

var fila; //captura la fila, para editar o eliminar
//submit para el Alta y Actualización
$('#formUsuarios').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //evita el comportambiento normal del submit, es decir, recarga total de la página
    nombre_usuario = $.trim($('#nombre_usuario').val());
    ip = $.trim($('#ip').val());
    plan = $.trim($('#plan').val());
    fecha_de_alta = $.trim($('#fecha_de_alta').val());
    caducidad = $.trim($('#caducidad').val());
    estado = $.trim($('#estado').val());
    observaciones = $.trim($('#observaciones').val());
        $.ajax({
          url: "bd/crud.php",
          type: "POST",
          datatype:"json",
          data:  {id:id, nombre_usuario:nombre_usuario, ip:ip, plan:plan, fecha_de_alta:fecha_de_alta, caducidad:caducidad , estado:estado , observaciones:observaciones,opcion:opcion},
          success: function(data) {
            tablaUsuarios.ajax.reload(null, false);
           }
        });
    $('#modalCRUD').modal('hide');
});

//para limpiar los campos antes de dar de Alta una Persona
$("#btnNuevo").click(function(){
    opcion = 1; //alta
    id=null;
    $("#formUsuarios").trigger("reset");
    $(".modal-header").css( "background-color", "#17a2b8");
    $(".modal-header").css( "color", "white" );
    $(".modal-title").text("Alta de Usuario");
    $('#modalCRUD').modal('show');
});

//Editar
$(document).on("click", ".btnEditar", function(){
    opcion = 2;//editar
    fila = $(this).closest("tr");
    id = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text()); //capturo el ID
    nombre_usuario = fila.find('td:eq(1)').text();
    ip = fila.find('td:eq(2)').text();
    plan = fila.find('td:eq(3)').text();
    fecha_de_alta = fila.find('td:eq(4)').text();
    caducidad = fila.find('td:eq(5)').text();
    estado = fila.find('td:eq(6)').text();
    observaciones = fila.find('td:eq(8)').text();
    $("#nombre_usuario").val(nombre_usuario);
    $("#ip").val(ip);
    $("#plan").val(plan);
    $("#fecha_de_alta").val(fecha_de_alta);
    $("#caducidad").val(caducidad);
    $("#estado").val(estado);
    $("#observaciones").val(observaciones);
    $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#007bff");
    $(".modal-header").css("color", "white" );
    $(".modal-title").text("Editar Usuario");
    $('#modalCRUD').modal('show');
});

//Borrar
$(document).on("click", ".btnBorrar", function(){
    fila = $(this);
    id = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text()) ;
    opcion = 3; //eliminar
    var respuesta = confirm("¿Está seguro de borrar el registro "+id+"?");
    if (respuesta) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "bd/crud.php",
          type: "POST",
          datatype:"json",
          data:  {opcion:opcion, id:id},
          success: function() {
              tablaUsuarios.row(fila.parents('tr')).remove().draw();
           }
        });
    }
 });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
    <title>DataTables</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css">

  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <button id="btnNuevo" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">library_add</i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="container caja">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="tablaUsuarios" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" style="width:100%" >
                    <thead class="text-center">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Nombre de Usuario</th>
                            <th>IP</th>
                            <th>Plan</th>
                            <th>Fecha de Alta</th>
                            <th>Caducidad</th>
                            <th>Fecha de Cierre</th>
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            <th>Obs/Coment</th>
                            <th>Acciones</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--Modal para CRUD-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalCRUD" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        <form id="formUsuarios">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" class="col-form-label">Nombre de Usuario:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_usuario">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" class="col-form-label">Ip</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ip">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" class="col-form-label">Plan</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="plan">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" class="col-form-label">Fecha de Alta</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fecha_de_alta">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="" class="col-form-label">Caducidad</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="caducidad">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="" class="col-form-label">Estado</label>
                        <select class="custom-select" id="estado">
  <option value="Activo">Activo</option>
  <option value="Suspendido">Suspendido</option>
</select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="" class="col-form-label">Observaciones - Comentarios</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="observaciones">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="submit" id="btnGuardar" class="btn btn-dark">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-e9gNBsAcA0DBuRWbm0oZfbiCyhjLrI6bmqAl5o+ZjUA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- extension responsive-->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

No se que libreria este mal o que deba modificar en el main.js para que al quedar responsive carguen los datos al modal y poder editar y que guarde la información.

Comment: Para lo responsive procura utilizar las clases adecuades para que se pueda adaptar, en mi caso las clases que utilizo son:                                                                         <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                 <!--Esta se encarga de renderizar de forma disponible los elementos en movil y pc -->
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: para la parte de llenar los datos del fomurlario, podrias ver la documentacion de boostrap, sin embargo tambien al dar click en el boon podrias pasar el id del item y en algun funcion ahcer una peticion ajax, para poder retornar los valores y asi asignarlos a variables para que puedas manipularlos en el DOM

Comment: agrego, puedo dar de alta registros mediante el modal pero no puedo editar ni eliminar creo algo mal con la variable fila

Comment: Si el modal los tienes en el mismo HTML, con el id del form y con los name del formulario puedes simplemente pasarlos

Comment: me puedes dar un ejemplo ya que como digo solo deja de funcionar el modal cuando es responsive la pagina, el modal tiene id y esta en mismo html, funciona en el ordenador pero en el movil siendo responsive la tabla no funciona para editar ni eliminar, si funciona para dar de alta.

Comment: Hola Alexis, has podido solucionarlo yo también tengo ese problema, alguna idea ??